# Cakephp App class code printing on the page and spl_autoload_register error

Tags: cakephp, exception, autoload, bootstrapping

I have moved the CakePHP installation from my development server to production server (Config file and htaccess updated).

The production server was using an older version of PHP and I have requested the host to upgrade it. After they upgraded the PHP version, the site printing the php code on the webpage (`Class : /lib/Cake/core/app`) .. Also it displaying a fatal error on the bottom of the page, its below

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Passed
>   array does not specify an existing static method (class 'App' not
>   found)' in /xxxxxxx/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php:154 Stack trace: #0
>   /xxxxxxx/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(154): spl_autoload_register(Array) #1
>   /xxxxxxx/app/webroot/index.php(92): include('/xxxxxxx/pu...') #2
>   {main} thrown in /xxxxxxx/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php on line 154

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the PHP version has actually changed, did you check (with phpinfo())?

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Yes, its changed, I checked using phpinfo()
 
PHP Version 5.3.23
Centos
LiteSpeed V6.1

Comment: is it somewhere we can see?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, CakePHP was unable to find or load the `App` class (`/xxxx/lib/Cake/core/App.php`).

It's possible that paths have changed since the update, however, (if you're using CakePHP 2.3.1) line 134 of that same file uses this to load that file:

```
require CAKE . 'Core' . DS . 'App.php';
```

If the file was not present or could not be loaded, the script should stop at that point.

To check if your paths are correct, try to debug that path;

```
 echo CAKE . 'Core' . DS . 'App.php'; die();
```

If that path is *correct* (my guess it is, otherwise the `require` should have stopped the script already as mentioned above), there is something wrong with the *content* of the `App.php` file. Maybe something corrupted the file (partial upload?) or incorrect line-endings caused PHP to interpret it incorrectly.

If the page is really showing the *complete source* of the App class, it may be possible you're (inadvertendly) using php 'short opening tags' and this has been disabled in the new configuration `<?` which may be cause, for example if a *space* is there is a space after the `<?` - `<? PHP`

More on short opening tags can be found here:

[Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)